# DynamoDB: What difference does it make whether I set an attribute to "NULL": "true" or just omit it?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have some items that I insert like this:

PutItem:

```
"TableName": "pets",
"Item": {
  "petName": {
      "S": "Cat"
    },
  "hairColor": {
      "S": "gray"
    },
  "nickName": {
      "S": "Kitty"
    }
 }
```

Sometimes however, the `pets` does not have a `nickname`. I'm pretty new to dynamoDB, and I can see, that I can handle this in two ways (at least):

1)

```
"TableName": "pets",
"Item": {
  "petName": {
      "S": "Cat"
    },
  "hairColor": {
      "S": "gray"
    },
  "nickName": {
      "NULL": "true"
    }
 }
```

2)

```
"TableName": "pets",
"Item": {
  "petName": {
      "S": "Cat"
    },
  "hairColor": {
      "S": "gray"
    }
 }
```

What difference will this make for me (e.g. when accessing the data afterwards)? And what is the best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting an attribute to "NULL" or omitting it **is not the same**.

If you do not set an attribute at all it obviously does not exist on the specific item. An attribute with the data type "NULL" however **does** exist but contains no value (similar to `null` in JSON).

E.g. when doing a comparison with the comparison operator `NULL` an attribute with the property "NULL" will actually be false. The naming here is very confusing but the behavior is quite [well documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html). For the comparison operator `NULL` it says:

> This operator tests for the nonexistence of an attribute, not its data
>   type. If the data type of attribute "a" is null, and you evaluate it
>   using NULL, the result is a Boolean false. This is because the
>   attribute "a" exists; its data type is not relevant to the NULL
>   comparison operator.